# Impulse response of a linear system

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am given an LTI system and its impulse response:

$$ h\left(t\right)=[te^{-4t}+2e^{-2t}]u\left(t\right) $$

Where

$$ u\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}
0 & t\leq0\\
1 & t>0
\end{cases} $$

And we are told that the system can be represented by a differential equation.

The question is; Can we identify the order of the system (the order of the differential equation) and the differential equation itself?

I thought about it, it seems that the characteristic polynomial has just 2 roots, and I can tell for sure that one of them (-4) has an algebraic multiplicity that is bigger than 1. But can we tell exactly what the differential equation would be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a good question.  What do _you_ think?  This is not a "do my homework for me" site.  Work this out and show your work.  Then if you have specific questions, ask them.

Comment: @jwh20 What could possibly be my work for the question "Can we decide the differential equation of a system just by looking at its Impulse response ? " Did I say "Find the differential equation for me " ? I literaly explained where Im struggeling to understand and I never mentioned anything about calculating the result for me. So if you cant help, you dont have to reply.

Comment: Try taking the Laplace transform of \$h(t)\$.  The necessary differential equation may not jump out of that and start pummeling you about the head and shoulders, but you'll be a lot closer to seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we identify the order of the system (the order of the differential equation)

Yes , we can identify the order !

One method could be to find  Laplace transform of $$h(t)$$
And  then  degree of denominator of polynomial $$H(s)$$ would be order of differential equation .

> and the differential equation itself?

Yes ! Use  $$H(s)=Y(s)/X(s)$$ then separate Y(s) and X(s) and then take inverse Laplace transform assuming Zero initial condition and you'll get desired differential equation.